# Running linux serial script in background

Tags: serial-port, debian, daemon

I'm running a simple script to connect to the serial port of my electricity monitor and save the output to a file:

```
cu -s 57600 -l /dev/ttyUSB0 >> /var/www/power.txt
```

I'd ideally like to set this off going in the background and leave it running, I think I might need a daemon for this? Does anyone have any experience using cu unattended?

Thanks,
Laurence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used `cu` before, but in general you can make a command run in the background by putting `&` after it.

e.g

```
cu -s 57600 -l /dev/ttyUSB0 >> /var/www/power.txt &
```

Comment: Switched to a perl script and used & to run that in the background, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can use dtach ( http://a.com.gt/rYL ) like this

`dtach -A /tmp/cu cu -s 57600 -l /dev/ttyUSB0 >> /var/www/power.txt`

This will run the process like in "background". You can close the termial or end your ssh connection and it will run until you cancel it.